# How do I prove that $\lim(2/3)^n=0$, by definition?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(2/3)^n=0$, by definition?
I need to find $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for every $n>N_{\epsilon}$:
$$\left|\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-0\right|<\epsilon.$$
How do I find the $N_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: Is an answer in terms of logarithms useful?

Comment: I don't see any thing wrong with logarithms at all but just be careful of signs and inequalities.  ${\frac 2 3}^n < \epsilon => {\frac 3 2}^n > \frac 1 {\epsilon} => n > \log_{\frac 3 2}{\frac 1 {\epsilon}}$ so let $N_{\epsilon} = \lceil  \log_{\frac 3 2}{\frac 1 {\epsilon}} \rceil$ will do it.  If it makes one more comfortable one can put it in terms of e and natural logs.  But egreg's answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that, for $x>-1$ and for any nonnegative integer $n$,
$$
(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx
$$
For $x=1/2$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\!n}\ge 1+\frac{1}{2}n
$$
that implies
$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\!n}> \frac{n}{2}
$$
(thanks to André Nicolas for suggesting the simplification). This last inequality can be written
$$
\frac{2^n}{3^n}<\frac{2}{n}
$$

Can you go on?

Comment: and for $x\ge 0$, the Bernoulli inequality is easy to see from the binomial theorem.

Comment: @BrianO Yes, of course. But a proof by induction is even simpler.

Comment: Sure. Just so that OP doesn't think it's some deep mystery — it's quite accessible.

Comment: @BrianO I added a link to Wikipedia

Comment: @egreg: While we are giving things away, we can observe that $1+\frac{1}{2}n\gt \frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

1. Simplify the expression $\left|\left(\frac23\right) - 0\right|$.
2. You now have a simpler expression $f(n) < \epsilon$, hopefully (if you did everything right) with $f$ being a monotonous bijective function.
3. Find the value of $n$ for which $f(n)=\epsilon$, and conclude that if $n$ is greater than that value, $f(n) < \epsilon$.

Comment: I have one question: We have $(2/3)^n<\epsilon$ then $n<\log_{2/3}{\epsilon}$. But our sign of ineqaulity must be converse. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @RaheemNajib If $0<a<1$, then $\log_a$ is a *decreasing* function.

Comment: @RaheemNajib $\log_\frac23x$ is not an increasing function.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use logs to a base between $0$ and $1$. Familiar sign relationships change, and it is easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Why our function must be increasing? Can you explain please?

Comment: @RaheemNajib If $x<y$ and $f$ is increasing, then you can say $f(x)<f(y)$. However, if you have a decreasing function, this is not true. Take, for example, $f(x)=-x$. You know that $1<2$, but that does not mean that $f(1)=-1<-2=f(2)$, right?

Comment: @5xum, Yes you are right! Thanks!